# Is it necessary to declare the datatype for a Double Pointer (a Pointer to a Pointer) if we are sure that we would not dereference it twice?

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

I was studying linked lists, and I had this question: *Why would we need to declare the datatype for a double pointer?* I think that, if you dereference such pointer (say `dptr` (a pointer to a pointer) ), you'd get a `pointer to insert_datatype`. Now if I were to just change this value, that is just changing where the `dptr` points to. And hence when I dereference this double pointer twice, I would still be dereferencing a structure (in my below code). So is it really necessary to declare the datatype for double pointers if we are using them to only dereference once? I can see why we would need to know the datatype while dereferencing the `dptr` twice, as `*dptr` would give us a `pointer to insert_datatype`, and when I do `**dptr`, it would be needed to know what is the datatype `*dptr` is pointing to.

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

void addAtBeg(int**, int);

int main(){
    int a;
    Node* head=NULL;
    printf("Enter data:\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    addAtBeg(&head,a);
    printf("%#x\n",head);
    printf("%d\n",(*head).data);
    return 0;
}

void addAtBeg(int** head, int a){
    Node* p;
    p=(Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->data=a;
    p->next=*head;
    *head=p;
}
```

I also can seem to just declare a `long long int* head` as the parameter receiving the `&head` in the `addAtBeg`, and it just works fine, as `*head=p` would just fetch 8 bytes, and write the memory address at that location.

So, are these both behaviors UB or are valid syntaxes?

Answer (score 1):

Pointers to different types don't necessarily have the same representation.  On most systems you're likely to come across this will be the case, but it's not true in general.

While it is legal to convert an object pointer of one type to an object pointer to another type and back, it is *not* allowed to dereference the converted pointer except in a few cases which don't apply here.

So this:

```
*head=p;
```

Triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Using either `int** head` *or* `long long int* head` in `addAtBeg`'s prototype is undefined behavior (specifically, the moment you do `*head = p;`, assigning a `Node*` to something that is thought to be a non-`Node*`). `long long int* head` is *worse*, in that it's far more likely to trigger a size mismatch (e.g. on 32 bit systems, the `Node*` you're dereferencing to will typically be 32 bits, while `long long int` is 64 bits, so the assignment would overwrite four bytes from neighboring value(s) on the stack). Both will *probably* work just fine (assuming you disable/ignore all warnings) up until the point where it turns out `sizeof(long long int) != sizeof(Node*)` or (less commonly) `sizeof(int*) != sizeof(Node*)`.

The real question is *why* you would do this? You still need to pass `&head` (that's unavoidable, `head` needs to be reassigned by the callee). There's no performance benefit. Since you're passing by pointer, you don't need the definition of `Node`, just a forward declaration if the declaration/definition isn't in that file. The function is replacing the pointer entirely, and is clearly aware it's working with a `Node`, so no information hiding or implementation details are being hidden from anyone. So what are you getting out of violating the type system?

Comment: I see, it makes sense. As to _why I am doing this_ , I was just playing around with pointers, trying to see how they worked.